# Jest: How to properly test console.error/console.warn with toThrowError?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

How can I test my function `calculateAverage` will throw an error (`console.error`) when an empty array is passed?

I'm using Jest to test, but can't get it working with `.toThrowError`.

**calculateAverage.test.tsx:**

```
// Imports: File
const { calculateAverage } = require('../calculateAverage');

// Calculate Average
describe('calculateAverage', () => {
  // Empty Array
  test('Throw Error on empty array', () => {
    expect(calculateAverage([])).toThrowError('Error: Empty Array (calculateAverage)');
  });

  // Test #1
  test('Test #1', () => {
    expect(calculateAverage([1, 2, 3])).toEqual(2);
  });

  // Test #2
  test('Test #2', () => {
    expect(calculateAverage([0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10])).toEqual(5);
  });
});
```

**calculateAverage.tsx:**

```
// Helper Function: Calculate Average
export const calculateAverage = (array: Array<number>) => {
  // Check If Data Exists
  if (array.length >= 1) {
    // Total
    let total: number = 0;

    // Iterate Over Array
    let i: number = 0;
    while (i < array.length) {
      // Add To Total
      total += array[i];

      // Increase I
      i++;
    }

    return total / array.length;
  }
  else {
    // Error
    console.error('Error: Empty Array (calculateAverage)');
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should `throw` error, not print the error using `console.error`.

Besides, from the [.toThrow(error?)](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#tothrowerror) doc:

> Note: You must wrap the code in a function, otherwise the error will not be caught and the assertion will fail.

E.g.

`calculateAverage.ts`:

```js
export const calculateAverage = (array: Array<number>) => {
  // Check If Data Exists
  if (array.length >= 1) {
    // Total
    let total: number = 0;

    // Iterate Over Array
    let i: number = 0;
    while (i < array.length) {
      // Add To Total
      total += array[i];

      // Increase I
      i++;
    }

    return total / array.length;
  } else {
    // Error
    throw new Error('Error: Empty Array (calculateAverage)');
  }
};
```

`calculateAverage.test.ts`:

```js
const { calculateAverage } = require('./calculateAverage');

// Calculate Average
describe('calculateAverage', () => {
  // Empty Array
  test('Throw Error on empty array', () => {
    expect(() => calculateAverage([])).toThrowError('Error: Empty Array (calculateAverage)');
  });

  // Test #1
  test('Test #1', () => {
    expect(calculateAverage([1, 2, 3])).toEqual(2);
  });

  // Test #2
  test('Test #2', () => {
    expect(calculateAverage([0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10])).toEqual(5);
  });
});
```

unit test result:

```js
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/65068033/calculateAverage.test.ts (13.57s)
  calculateAverage
    ✓ Throw Error on empty array (13ms)
    ✓ Test #1 (3ms)
    ✓ Test #2 (1ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       3 passed, 3 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        14.785s
```

Comment: Thank you for your help and clarification!!